# ¿Como ejecutar varios métodos con un solo botón en Netbeans y MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Por favor quisiera me puedan ayudar... no se como llamar a varios métodos de una clase a un botón de un formulario. Me explico, cuando doy clic en el botón quiero que me guarde, actualice y pase datos de una tabla a otra en la base de datos, no se si se pueda hacer eso... la verdad no se como hacerlo!!!
Bueno aquí el código de los métodos:

```
 public void importarHorario(String url)
  {
  url=url.replace("\\", "/");

  PreparedStatement pst;
  try {
      pst=cn.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+url+"' INTO TABLE tb_horariodocentes_org FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'(codigo_personal, dia, seccion_malla_numeroHora, hora_inicio, hora_fin, materia,carrera, aula) ");
      pst.executeQuery();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Guardado con Exito!!!");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido Guardar");
  }
}

  public void ActualizarDatosHorario() {

    try {
        pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE tb_horariodocentes_org, tb_horariotrabajo SET tb_horariodocentes_org.hora_inicio = tb_horariotrabajo.horaInicia, tb_horariodocentes_org.hora_fin = tb_horariotrabajo.horaFin where tb_horariodocentes_org.seccion_malla_numerohora = tb_horariotrabajo.codigo");
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Actualizados");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pueden Actualizar los datos");
    }

}

public void PasarDatosHorarios() {

    try {
        String consulta = "insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, hora_entrada, hora_salida, numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo, j_codigo) select codigo_personal, substring(dia,1,1) AS dia,  min(hora_inicio), MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as malla, 1,1\n"
                + "from tb_horariodocentes_org\n"
                + "where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='D' \n"
                + "GROUP by codigo_personal,dia\n"
                + "ORDER by 2,3,5";

        String consulta1 = "insert into tb_horarios(codigopersonal, dia, hora_entrada, hora_salida, numero_horas, malla_referencia, prd_codigo) select codigo_personal, substring(dia,1,1) AS dia, min(hora_inicio), MAX(hora_fin),COUNT(DISTINCT seccion_malla_numerohora),substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,2,1) as malla, tb_periodo.codigo\n"
                + "from tb_horariodocentes_org, tb_periodo\n"
                + "where   substring(seccion_malla_numerohora,1,1)='N' and tb_periodo.codigo='2'\n"
                + "GROUP by codigo_personal,dia\n"
                + "ORDER by 2,3,5";

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        st.addBatch(consulta);
        st.addBatch(consulta1);
        st.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ConsultasBD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}
```

Aquí lo que tengo en el botón Guardar. El método de guardar lo tengo en una clase y los métodos de actualizar en otra:

```
private void btn_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    GuardarArchivos gad= new GuardarArchivos();
    gad.importarHorario(url);
    ConsultasBD cbd = new ConsultasBD();
    cbd.ActualizarDatosHorario();
    cbd.PasarDatosHorarios();

}
```

Comment: Se puede hacer, pero necesitamos saber que lo has intentado como así también como es la estructura de tu código actual. Realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para tener una mejor calidad de preguntas y respuestas. Saludos-

Answer (score 1):

Cómo [Lucas D](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6881/lucas-d) comentó, se puede hacer eso, pero si tu quieres tornar el código en el botón más sencillo, usted puede crear una nueva clase responsable por las llamadas, seria una clase con las reglas del negocio:

```
public class Ejemplo{

    public void guardar(String url){
        GuardarArchivos gad= new GuardarArchivos();
        gad.importarHorario(url);
        ConsultasBD cbd = new ConsultasBD();
        cbd.ActualizarDatosHorario();
        cbd.PasarDatosHorarios();
    }

}
```

Y en el botón usted llama la nueva clase:

```
private void btn_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
    ejemplo.guardar(url);
}
```